# How do I embed external file to the rest of the resources in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

Imagine there is an mmo game client made in Unity. As you may know, in mmo games, clients don't come with all the resources. They simply download the missing resources from the server, usually while loading the game. Unity builds have their resources embedded in a file format of its own.

I've tried to search on unity's forum but couldn't find a proper solution.

How do I put the downloaded file into the embedded resources so it doesn't have to be downloaded each time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity3d has a mechanism called AssetBundles for such tasks. Every asset bundle is an archive with the assets that can be loaded into the game. Once the asset bundle is loaded, it is stored in the device's local cache and will only be re-downloaded in case it is updated or deleted by the user.

However, asset bundles themselves do not provide a mechanism for loading from the internet, unloading resources automatically, etc. So you will need a wrapper for this.

You can use Unity3d native wrapper above the asset bundles, which is called Addressables (https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/com.unity.addressables.html) or write your own wrapper (but it is not a trivial task).